Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are open subsets of $X$ s.t $\overline{A} = X = \overline{B}$. Prove $\overline{A \cap B}=X$
I stumbled upon these topology Materials. I was working through homework two and found this problem:
Problem:
Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are open subsets of $X$ with $\overline{A} = X = \overline{B}$. Prove that $\overline{A \cap B} = X$.

Now:
The set $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}\}$ is a valid topology on $\mathbb{R}$. However, we have
$$
\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \overline{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R} \quad \text{but} \quad \overline{\mathbb{Q} \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})} = \overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset \neq \mathbb{R}.
$$
Am I missing something or is there an error here?

Let me rephrase this... suppose $A, B$ are open dense sets, prove that $A\cap B$ is an open dense set.

In your topology $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ are both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$, so that their closure is again themselves, and not $\mathbb{R}$.

Actually, with respect to that topology you have $\overline{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb Q$ and $\overline{\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

For the solution of the problem see this post.

In case you are asking for a proof, this is a duplicate.

Writing up the answer in the comments:
While $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$ in the standard topology, this is not true in the four-set topology you provide. Indeed, since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is an open set, its complement $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed, so $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{Q}$ (since it is clearly the smallest closed set containing $\mathbb{Q}$). Similarly, $\overline{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
So we have that neither $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ nor $\overline{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, and thus the statement does not apply.
